# Pubnub subsriptions lost after a few time

Tags: android, publish-subscribe, pubnub

I'm trying to use Pubnub android API to include inside another app the realtime chat feature. I tried to use basic API functionalities in order to be familiar with it and to understand how it works, but I have a big problem.
When the chat starts, I must know which conversations are "active" for me, that is, which are all chats I joined to. 
According to the [API reference](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android-java/api-reference#where_now) to do this it will be sufficient to call `pubnub.whereNow(<my uuid>)` so I "obtain information about the current list of a channels to which a uuid is subscribed to". But when I tried to subscribe to a channel, after a few minutes (maybe 5 mins) the `whereNow()` method's callback returns an empty list!!! Is it acceptable to lose my channel subscription?? If true, this would mean that if I start a chat room I will be able to receive messages only during first 5 minutes, and it clearly makes no sense. Do I have to store inside my app all channels I subscribed to and re-subscribe to them?

Comment: Hi!  This sounds like a configuration option.  Send a note to support@pubnub.com via email.  We'll work over the details with you.

Comment: Are you offline for more than 5 minutes and then you come back online and do a where-now?

Comment: No. I am always online. I simply tried to do not send any message. About this, I noted that if messages are continuously exchanged we have no problems. Because of this, I guess sending some messages always 'refreshes' subscriptions. In any case, this makes no sense

Comment: Have you tried the `whereNow` with just the callback param (no UUID). It uses the current client's UUID by default - just want to know if that makes a difference. If not, then can you send log file to [PubNub Support](http://www.pubnub.com/support)? You can enable [debug mode using the PubNub debug jar](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/java-se-java/pubnub-java-sdk-troubleshooting-guide).

Comment: Did you ever contact PubNub support with log file or try the "no uuid" method?